# Model-Binding a Stream Instance

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I want to upload stream file to controller.The methods of it are implemented from abstract controller. To bind Stream;

```
public class StreamInputFormatter : IInputFormatter
{
    // enter your list here...
    private readonly List<string> _allowedMimeTypes = new List<string>
        { "application/pdf", "image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/tiff", "image/tif", "application/octet-stream,","multipart/form-data" };

    public bool CanRead(InputFormatterContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        var contentType = context.HttpContext.Request.ContentType;
        if (_allowedMimeTypes.Any(x => x.Contains(contentType)))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public Task<InputFormatterResult> ReadAsync(InputFormatterContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        // enable stream rewind or you won't be able to read the file in the controller   
        var req = context.HttpContext.Request;
        req.EnableRewind();

        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        context.HttpContext.Request.Body.CopyTo(memoryStream);
        req.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        return InputFormatterResult.SuccessAsync(memoryStream);
    }
}
```

Whenever I send request to method which throws the error :

> Could not create an instance of type 'System.IO.Stream'. Model bound complex types must not be abstract or value types and must have a parameterless constructor.

*Here is my controller*

```
public override async Task<IActionResult> PostParentChildAvatar([FromForm] Stream file)
{
    var accountName = _configuration.GetValue<string>(AccountName);
    var key = _configuration.GetValue<string>(Key);
    var blobServiceEndpoint = _configuration.GetValue<string>(BlobServiceEndpoint);
    var containerName = _configuration.GetValue<string>(ContainerName);

    var storageService = new StorageService(accountName, key, blobServiceEndpoint, containerName);

    var avatar = await storageService.CreateFileWithStreamAsync(file);

    return Ok(new AvatarViewModel()
    {
        Id = Guid.Parse(avatar.Id.Substring(0,avatar.Id.Length - 4)),
        Url = avatar.FileUrl
    });
}
```

Comment: There's no real benefit to trying to push a `Stream` through the model-binding process. Instead, you can just read from `Request.Body`.